# Tweepy: simple script with 'Bad Authentication data' error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is this really an authentication problem or has it to do with something else? 
What do I have to modify to get rid of the error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy

ckey = 'xxx'
csecret = 'xxx'
atoken = 'xxx'
asecret = 'xxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

results = tweepy.api.search(geocode='50,50,5mi')

for result in results:
    print result.text
    print result.location if hasattr(result, 'location') else "Undefined location"
```

This is the error I get

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/untitled/testfile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/untitled/testfile.py", line 18, in <module>
    results = tweepy.api.search(geocode='50,50,5mi')
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 197, in _call
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 173, in execute
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data', u'code': 215}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your doing it wrong:

It should be-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy

ckey = 'xxx'
csecret = 'xxx'
atoken = 'xxx'
asecret = 'xxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# here's where you went wrong (tried and tested), should be
#results = api.search(geocode='50,50,5mi')
# try with the following lat long
results = api.search(geocode='39.833193,-94.862794,5mi') 

for result in results:
    print result.text
    print result.location if hasattr(result, 'location') else "Undefined location"
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped to eliminate the error. But I didn't get any results printed out.

Comment: Your coordinates did the job. Thanks.But why it doesn't work with my coordinates? I tried other coordinates and get the same results as before: none.

Comment: I'm not really sure why! But do the co-ordinates your provide exist really?

Comment: Yes, they exist. I tried it out with New York (40.7144, -74.0060). No results!